# Append variables to URI in a generic way (adding ? or & when necessary)

Tags: php, html, forms, uri, parameter-passing

I am a beginner in PHP and currently, to post variables in uri addresses I use:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."&myvar=".$myvar."'>";
```

but it does not work when the URI is just something like `wwww.mysite.com/index` because there is no parameters yet (and so no `?` after the main address). So how to pass the php parameters in the address in a generic way ?

Comment: Use ? Instead of & for first parameter

Comment: The whole point is that I want this to be generic (when I add something I do not know if it is the 1st or the 1834th parameter...)

Comment: You might want to set a function that counts parametrs and will add ? To the first and & for the others throw a loop. If uri already has parameters you will need to parse it and add in the functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url), [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str), and [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query):

```
// build URL with query
function q($url, array $params) {
    return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) . '?' . http_build_query($params);
}

// build URL and expand query
function qe($url, array $new_params, $overwrite = true) {
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
    if ($overwrite) {
        $new_params = $new_params + $params;
    } else {
        $new_params = $params + $new_params;
    }
    return q($url, $new_params);
}

$url = qe($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], array('myvar' => $myvar));
echo "<form method='POST' action='".htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES)."'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the existance of any chars first. E.g.

```
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (substr_count($link, '?') == 0) {
  $link .= '?';
}
echo "<form method='POST' action='".$link."&myvar=".$myvar."'>";
```

Comment: In fact the '?' is not necessary the last character

Comment: I realised after I posted the wrong function - replaced with `substr_count`.

Comment: Your code works wrong if URI doesn't contain query string. E.g. for `REQUEST_URI = "mysite.com/index"` it returns `"mysite.com/index?&myvar=$myvar"`